# The resource type 'XXXX.XXX' does not have a publicly visible static property named '_RequiredXXXX'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

> "'ErrorMessageResourceType' property specified was not found."
>   {"The resource type 'XXXX.XXXXXX' does not have a publicly visible static property named '_RequiredXXXX'."}

I'm getting this error when my Create.aspx view is called and steps over that line:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.NO_DEMND, New With {.class = "txtbox", .disabled = True})%>
<%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.NO_DEMND)%>
```

The message is there in the Ressources file, I think the problem is deeper than that but i'm having a hard time finding it. It pops this error very early on the ASPX page. It's the first model component it goes thru, i tried removing this one and it's the same message for all the model.xxxx components. I guess it's an error somewhere in the linkage. The .EDMX is correct and I get no build errors, can anyone enlight me ?

Thanks alot
Tom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer, turns out we had the same bug last year working on this project.
I'll add the answer for the sakes of knowledge and sO :-)

Right click on the affected Resources file to get the properties.

Set those values:

1. Build Action: Embedded Resource
2. Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
3. Custom Tool Namespace: Resources

Hope it helps anyone in the near futur since it took me 4hrs to figure this out...

Tom.

Comment: Tommy, this error just happened to me. Weird thing is it only happens with a recently new entry on the .resx file. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution and keep getting this. Any idea why it would not work? regards

Comment: Can you try deleting the .resx, bringing it back, make sure the values stated above are set and then build ?

Comment: I had to create a new set of resx files (SharedResources.resx - the main one - open it up and set access modifier to 'public', then run Custom Tool on SharedResources.resx. Then created SharedResources.fr.resx making sure access modifier also public and so on with the rest of the files. Note: This didn't work when my main file was SharedResources.en.resx

Answer (score 0):

[image: Changing the build action property of my resource file to content resolved the error.]

Changing the build action property of my resource file to content resolved the error